# How to use freemarker in C#

Tags: c#, .net, freemarker

I have a scenario where I have to use the existing freemarker templates used in a java application to a new .NET application. I searched on the web and got freemarker.net as an equivalent which uses some IKVM as a wrapper and does the formatting of templates [here](https://freemarkernet.codeplex.com/). The problem here is there are around 5 million templates which I need to pull from database and they contain some placeholders which have a different syntax in .net. For example
In .NET we have

```
<#list sequence as item>
Part repeated for each item
```

In existing java template we have

```
<list sequence as item>
Part repeated for each item
</list>
```

The problem is I need to change all the existing 5 million templates based on the freemarker .NET version that I am using, which does not seems to be a feasible solution. So I need to find a solution where I can use the same templates without much of a change.
A sample template that I have to convert is

```
Dear ${name},        
<if account_type_id=="some ID">Some Content. 
<else>Some Content. </if>
```

I have to change this to

```
Dear ${name},        
<#if account_type_id=="some ID">Some Content. 
<#else>Some Content. <#/if>
```

In the same way there are many markups that need to be changed.

Comment: Seems to me like a quite straightforward "find&replace" task. The list of Freemarker directives is known, so it should be quite easy to write a perl/awk/python/you_name_it script to go through all the templates and replace `<directive` with `<#directive` etc.

Comment: No, the list of all the Freemarker directives are not known, also the freemarker.net dll has a performance impact.

Comment: http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_alphaidx.html

Comment: If anyone has worked on freemarker implementation of .NET, then a better implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: Achieving reasonable FreeMarker 2.3.x compatibility in a Net rewrite would be a huge work, so I doubt that FreeMarker.net does that. Though your templates use FreeMarker 1.x-style, so perhaps they only use a small subset of the features. In that case, perhaps parsing  and transforming them to some Net-native template language is the best compromise.

Comment: Since we are rewriting an existing Java application to .NET and we may have to switch between the Java and .NET versions, changing the template data might not be a feasible option as it has to be in working condition for both Java and .NET versions.